# Passing an array of objects through props in React

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, react-props

(Solved): Solution was compatibility issues between chart.js and the react version. The recent update to the react version solved it.

I was having trouble finding the solution to this, maybe someone will know why this error is happening:
I am passing an object array via props, but I'm getting an error when it comes to using the prop:
Object array sample (The data for score is fed in through an API and is working):

```
var teamData = [
  {
    teamName: "Cowboys",
    score: 0,
    color: "rgba(0, 34, 68, 0.9)",
  },
  {
    teamName: "Cardinals",
    score: 0,
    color: "rgba(135, 0, 39, 0.9)",
  },
  {
    teamName: "Patriots",
    score: 0,
    color: "rgba(0, 21, 50, 0.9)",
  },
  {
    teamName: "49ers",
    score: 0,
    color: "rgba(170, 0, 0.9)",
  },
```

App.js example

```
const App = () => {
  getData();
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <BarChart teamData={teamData} />
      <Calculator teamData={teamData} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And here is where I pass the props to insert one by one into a chart.js component({props[0].score} is where the error is, it says: `SyntaxError C:\Users\name\Documents\Websites\React Based\madden-ranker\src\components\BarChart.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (14:37):`

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar, HorizontalBar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const BarChart = (props) => {

  return (
    <HorizontalBar
      // prettier-ignore
      data={{
                labels: ['Team1' ],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Cumulative Score',
                        data: [{props[0].score}, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 10, 20],
                        backgroundColor: []

                    },
                ],
            }}
      height={500}
      width={600}
      options={{
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

Interestingly, I tried console logging it inside the teamData component and got this:
line5: console.log(props);
line6: console.log(props.teamData[0].score);

[image: Image of error]

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition to check if props[0] exists before rendering, cause the first time the props is empty, and when you setstate after getting data from API the component rerenders. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: When I console logged it, it outputs props just fine, it's just selecting the array[x] and the .score. For some reason, that doesn't get found. For the API, I am grabbing it from the API and putting it into a var array anyways, so shouldn't the state be fine if it shows the array when I console log props?

Comment: Did you use console.log in parent or child component? If array[] and the .score doesn't get found that means the props did not get passed. Put a console log in child component and see when the data is loading using useffect hook. Hope it helps.

Comment: I consoled the child component. When I do: console.log(props); I get the full array with the API updated variables, but I just did console.log(props.teamData[0].score); and I got the 0 variable I initiated with. I'm not sure why that is. I believe I should be using setState() to update the state, but I am not relying on the data to be updated often. A simple page refresh is good enough since it updates every 3 days.

Comment: The output is above on the console log

Comment: change {props[0].score} -> props[0].score

Comment: Check this documentation, https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/example/src/charts/HorizontalBar.js You need to use Bar and not HorizontalBar. I've created a sandbox for you which mimics what you're trying to do. Please have a look, hope it helps. https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-wood-jl8ts

Comment: wow, it worked.... thanks! I honestly don't think I would have ever realized it was a chart.js problem because I followed a tutorial of how to set it up and that was what was shown. I didn't set state, which I now realize was necessary, though I am lost at how with all of that added, doing import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2"; works with state, but import  {Bar, HorizontalBar} from "react-chartjs-2"; doesn't work.... I assume this has to do with HorizontalBar doesn't work with hooks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231680/discussion-between-submersed24-and-user3233110).

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a few commas in places that they shouldn't be

Try this

```
   const BarChart = (props) => {

      return (
        <HorizontalBar
          // prettier-ignore
          data={{
                    labels: ['Team1' ],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Cumulative Score',
                            data: [{props[0].score}, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 100, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 10, 20],
                            backgroundColor: []
    
                        }
                    ]
                }}
          height={500}
          width={600}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
              }
            }
          }}
        />
      );
    };
```

Comment: Still no luck. That part is definitely working though, since it does work with numbers, just not with props included.